# Other sources of Adventure Time?

Tags: adventure-time

What Adventure Time merchandise, including books, comics, and video games serve as canonical extensions to the story? All of these should be in a list. Including Marcy's Scrapbook and  the name of the Adventure Time Comics, what other elements are part of the story? (How many issues of the comic are out?)

Comment: related, not dupe - [Are the Adventure Time comics canon?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17277/are-the-adventure-time-comics-canon)

Answer (score 2):

Adventure Time canon items.

- The TV Show (obviously).
- The tie-in TV show, [Stakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakes_(miniseries))
- The [Comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17278/20774), except where they conflict with the TV shows.

> *So yeah, **the comics are as canonical as possible**, and we put a lot of
> work into making sure that everything fits! But future episodes might
> contradict something, and then we’ll say “Hey, they’re still
> canonical, but Abracadaniel spilled just some some magic on that one
> page of the comic and changed all our memories of it and that’s why it
> doesn’t make sense anymore!!”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ryan North Tumblr](http://ryannorth.tumblr.com/post/23729809967/something-that-comes-up-pretty-often-is-this)</sup></sub>

Or possibly not

> *Are the Adventure Time comics canon?*
>
> ***No, not really.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Ask Adam Muto](http://ask.fm/MrMuto/answers/134245195208)</sup></sub>

- The Video Game "[Adventure Time Explore the Dungeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_Time:_Explore_the_Dungeon_Because_I_Don%27t_Know!)"

> *"**It will be canon** and will tie into the show," Blean said, noting it's
> very possible the show could pick up the game's plot. He also said the
> game will finally reveal Princess Bubblegum's true age — "she is quite
> old," he said — and why she has built this dungeon.*
>
> <sub><sup>[New Adventure Time game has plenty of big plot reveals tied to the show](http://www.polygon.com/2013/10/11/4828826/adventure-time-game-has-a-big-plot-reveal-tied-to-the-show)</sup></sub>

- Marcy's Super-Secret Scrapbook

> ***Are Marcy's Super Secret Scrapbook and the newest comic book special
> canon to the show?***
>
> ***The new book is much closer to the show's canon than a lot of the
> previous books. I haven't read the final version yet, though, so I
> can't say it's 100%**. There are probably some liberties taken for jokes
> or to make it flow better. Ideally, **Hanna's comic will be 100%
> consistent with the show's continuity**. But I haven't seen the final
> version of that yet either.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ask Adam Muto](http://ask.fm/MrMuto/answers/133549629128)</sup></sub>